# How to get navbar to show fully and be center aligned

Tags: html, css, alignment, navbar

I am using a responsive nav bar so when the width of the screen falls below 600px, the nav bar turns into a dropdown list. The nav bar IS working, except it looks dreadful.

1. The elements are all on the left and wont spread evenly across the page. I used a float left so they would display in a horizontal line.
2. The headings are spilling onto new lines. I want the headings to just flow out on one line

HTML:

```
<ul class="topnav">
    <li><a href="Sustainability.html">Sustainability</a></li>
    <li><a href="Climate%20Change.html">Climate Change</a></li>
    <li><a href="Home%20Page.html"><img src="Images/Climate-Hikewhite.png" height="50px" href="Home%20Page.html" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="DIY.html">How You Can Help</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
/* NAV BAR*/
ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #000;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 24px;
}

ul.topnav li {
    float:left;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

 }

ul.topnav li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #EEE;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;    
    width: 20%;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.active) {color: green;}

ul.topnav li a.active {background-color: #4CAF50;}

ul.topnav li.right {float: right;}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
ul.topnav li.right, 
ul.topnav li {float: none;}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your CSS to use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Use flex in the parent navigation and center it. On your media query change the direction of the elements to a column. The `nth-child(3)` is for visibility purpose just so that the image is on top. Hope this helps.

```css
.topnav{
  display: flex;
  list-style:none;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #000;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  align-items: center;
}
.topnav li{
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.topnav a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
.topnav{
  flex-direction: column;
}
.topnav li{
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.topnav li:nth-child(3){
  order: -1;
}

}
```

```html
<ul class="topnav">
    <li><a href="Sustainability.html">Sustainability</a></li>
    <li><a href="Climate%20Change.html">Climate Change</a></li>
    <li><a href="Home%20Page.html"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" height="50px" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="DIY.html">How You Can Help</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```